# Mapping over X items in React and then conditionally render for items that were not in the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a Movie DB app that lets users add movies to their watchlist. Now the issue is that I want to create a 5 column / 4 rows layout, since I always get exactly **20** movies back when fetching from the API.

I want to keep this layout on my Watchlist page by mapping over the current watchlist and render these and then for the remainder of the items (if the watchlist only held 3 movies for instance) create 17 empty divs.

I don't have a clue how I would set this up in React. I imagine using a for loop or is there another way with map that I'm missing?

TLDR; I want to render exactly 20 divs on my page. Some div's will be containing the users movie they want to watch (done by mapping over watchlist array). I want to render the remaining divs, so the ones that don't contain a movie, to have 20 divs in total. How would I do this with .map?

My current set-up:

```
const Movies = ({movies, resetPage, isLoading, addToWatchList}) => {
    return (
        <div className="movies"> 
            {
                movies.map((movie) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={movie.id} className="movies__item">
                            <Link
                                to={`/movie/${movie.id}`}
                                onClick={resetPage}
                            >                        
                            {isLoading ? 
                            <ClipLoader                    
                                size={60}
                                color={"#D72525"}
                                loading={!!isLoading}
                            /> 
                            : 
                                <img
                                    key={movie.id}
                                    src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${movie.poster_path}`}
                                    className="movies__item-img"
                                    alt={`A poster of ${movie.title}`}
                                ></img>}                            
                            </Link>

                            <button onClick={() => addToWatchList(movie)} className="movies__item--button">Add To WatchList</button> 
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you can ***Array(...).fill(...)*** to serve the purpose.

```
<div className="movies"> 
        {
            movies.map((movie) => {
                return (
                    <div key={movie.id} className="movies__item">
                        ...........
                        ...........
                    </div>
                )
            })
         }
         {
           Array(20-movies.length).fill(
                    ............ 
                    [YOUR_EMPTY_DIVS HERE]
                    ............
                        )
         }
    </div>
```

Comment: I've edited my post for clarification. I don't want to fill the array itself, I just want to render 'empty divs' to fill up the space, so I'll always have exactly 20 items rendered on the page.

Comment: You will get movies div by your map, the rest empty are generated by Array()....

Comment: Give it a try, I also did the same way. Let me know if u r feeling confused to use that.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, it's exactly what I wanted! And yes, I'm a bit confused on what's exactly happening here. Could you perhaps shed some light on the fill method?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly. I make a new array that gets filled with for example: 17 <a> tags if movies.length is 3? How does it loop over these and why can this array hold JSX?

Comment: In this case, Array(17) is returning an array undefined. Now your are replacing those elements with JSX object with fill() method.

Comment: You can mark this answer right, so that other people can find this helpful.